# I cannot stop Location service from my fragment. How can stop it?

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-ondestroy

I start my service from onCreateView like

```
getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), LocationService.class));
```

And I try to stop my service like this

```
    @Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(),LocationService.class));
    super.onDestroyView();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), LocationService.class));
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), LocationService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't used LocationManager in my service class but I used GoogleApiClient and after a lot try I used following code in onDestroy(). Finally, it is done.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `stopService` should suffice - even once in `onDestroy`. Make sure you actually implement `onDestroy` in your service and unregister your LocationListener inside it.

Answer (score 0):

try this method of locationmanager in onStop or ondestroy method of servise

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationTracker.this);
```

These day u can use googleplaces for location it provides simple implementation Refer here:- http://coderzpassion.com/android-location-using-google-play-services/